# I am confused about how to create this command prompt menu which has 5 different user-input functions

Tags: algorithm, menu, command-prompt

[ Editing for Archiving Purposes. This question has reached its answer.]

This is, once again, a programming assignment that seems to build off of the chapter contents, and yet, the assignment itself is unique to the chapters I've had to read.

I was attempting to create a program  that requests a user to first input three integers separated by spaces. This program will then open an "Analysis Menu, with 5 different Cases in Command Prompt, where the input of a number ranging from 1-5 will calculate the Average, the Maximum, the Minimum, or the Total of the 3 digits provided; or, if 5 is pressed, exit the program altogether. I was confused how to make such a menu until I eventually came to the conclusion to use a switch command to make a menu in the following manner:

```
>import java.util.Scanner; // imports Scanner class

public class Analysis
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int n1, n2, n3, n4;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in);
    while ( true )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Please give three integers separated by spaces: " );
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        n2 = sc.nextInt();
        n3 = sc.nextInt();

        // building a menu
        System.out.println( "\n****** Analysis Menu ******" );
        System.out.println( "1: Average" );
        System.out.println( "2: Maximum" );
        System.out.println( "3: Minimum" );
        System.out.println( "4: Total" );
        System.out.println( "5: Exit" );
        System.out.println( "*******************\n" );

        n4 = sc.nextInt(); // get the user selection

        if ( n4 == 1 )
            System.out.print( "  " );
        else if ( n4 == 2 )
            System.out.print( "  " );
        else if ( n4 == 3 ) 
            System.out.print( "  " );
        else if ( n4 == 4 )
            System.out.print( "  " );
        else if ( n4 == 5 )
            System.out.print( "  " );
```

The Print lines of Code for each of the If and Else If statements is acting as a placeholder, because I'll need to tinker around with putting in Arithmetic Algorithms for Average, Maximum, Minimum, Total, and Exit. The Exit one will be the hardest because I can not find that in my chapter. End result will be:

[Photobucket Image taken from my Programming Assignment Description.](http://i1221.photobucket.com/albums/dd478/7vincent7black7/Private%20things/Capture_zpsb41768d1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is really nothing more than a few print statements followed by an input statement.  You could have just a single input statement with a bunch of carriage returns in the string, but that would not look nice to maintain as well as being more error prone.

Comment: I just saw a switch command on a similar thread I hadn't seen earlier. I'm thinking using a switch command with cases 1-5 may be what the teacher has in mind. Where each case will perform a different arithmetic algorithm?